# Appirio Cloud Sync on Group Edition

Tags: appexchange, group-edition

I have an issue while using Appirio Cloud Sync on Group Edition of salesforce. It seems that although the app is available for install it queries Contact records with some fields non existing in the Group Edition.

Error I get in an email from the job:

> **Appirio Cloud Sync**
>
> Exception Notification Your Contacts sync failed to execute:
>   Salesforce call failed:
>   Id,OwnerId,FirstName,LastName,Description,Email,IsDeleted,LastModifiedDate
>   ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:38 No such column Description on entity
>   Contact. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to
>   append the __c after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL
>   or the describe call for the appropriate names.

The thing is the Description field is shown on the field list for contact object

```
Description Description Long Text Area(32000)
```

Please help.

In the meantime i will try Companion Link and report abou it.

Comment: Is Description on the page layout? If not, you can't access it by the API. This would cause the error presented.

Comment: yes you're right it's working that way. Now i have to see where to add all the fields so they don't corrupt the layout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Professional Edition without custom profiles/page layouts, and in Group Edition, any fields not present on the layout are hidden from reports and API calls. When fields error out when you know they exist, this will be the most likely problem.